# Unchecking checkbox using different Id's

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have the following 2 checkboxes that i need to deselect once the other one is selected.

```
  <div class="header">
           <h3 class="checkout-headers">STEP 3 - Billing Information </h3>
          <!--START: sameAsBilling1-->
<!--value="ON"-->
          <div class="sameAsBilling1">
            <input type="checkbox" name="sameAsBilling" id="sameAsBilling" value="1" onclick="showHideShipping();check_address('');"/>
            <label for="sameAsBilling">Same as Delivery Address</label>
            <div class="clear"></div>
          </div>
            <div class="differentBilling">
                <input type="checkbox" class="example" id="check2" value="2" onclick="myFunction2()"; return false;>Different Billing Address?</div>
          <!--END: sameAsBilling1-->
          <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
```

The function i'm using is this;

```
          <script>
                var $ = jQuery;
var chk1 = $("#sameAsBilling");
var chk2 = $("#check2");

//check the other box
chk1.on('click', function(){
  if( chk1.is(':checked') ) {
    chk2.attr('checked', true);
  } else {
    chk2.attr('checked', false);
  }
});
</script>
```

The issue now is the checkboxes on deselect when both are selected and i go to unselect the sameAsBilling button.

Answer (score 1):

Because `.on()` is not a function on [the `Element` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element), which is [what `getElementById()` returns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).  It *is*, however, a function on the jQuery object.  If that's what you meant to use:

```
var chk1 = $("#sameAsBilling");
var chk2 = $("#check2");
```

Comment: Thankyou i've updated my answer. However, now i'm getting another error; the checkboxes only deselect when i both are checked and i go to uncheck the sameAsBilling checkbox. Obviously, i want them to deselect once the other one has been selected.

Comment: @johndoi: Your question is a moving target at this point, and ongoing edits are invalidating existing answers.  If you have a separate question, please ask it separately.  For the question you're asking now, you'd also do well to step through your code in the browser's debugger and indicate specifically where the logic is behaving differently from what you expect.  Often this process reveals the problem in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to David's answer, you can use plain JS:

Instead of

`chk1.on('click', function(){..`

You can use

`chk1.addEventListener("click", function( event )..`

It is not clear whether you meant to tag `jQuery` or just `JavaScript` (looks like it could go either way.